# how to collapse width of parent element to total width of child elements

Tags: html, css

My parent width takes up the whole 100% width of parent element.

Instead, I want parent width to collapse to total width of child elements.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/z9Unk/232/

Notice how red-bordered parent width is greater than total width of green-colore child elements. I want to collapse the parent width.

Please advise necessary changes.

HTML

```
<div class="item1">
  <div class="item2">
      item2
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
      item2
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item1 {
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:2px solid red;
}

.item2 {
 position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  width : 255px;
  height : 205px;
  margin-right:6px;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: mark the method that worked the best for you as the answer for the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.item1` is a block-level element which takes 100% of width of its parent by default.

You could change type of *display* of `.item1` element to `table` or `inline-block`:

```css
.item1 {
    /*  other CSS declarations */
    /* display: inline-block; */ /* Or */
    display: table;
}
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/z9Unk/235/)**.

---

**Note:** If Internet Explorer doesn't run in *compatibility view*, there would be **no problem**.

However to force IE to run in standard mode, you could add following `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` section:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hope you dont have issues with internet explorer

Answer (score 0):

the Item1 will always expand to the width of its parent because it is set as display:block.

one way to fix this is to add to Item1:

> float:left

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the `fit-content` value for the CSS property `width`. But it is supported only by Firefox and Chrome…

Example :

```
.item1 {
  position:relative
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```